# Is small scale distributed computing possible over a home network?

Tags: networking, virtualization, processing

Is there any way to set up a distributed computing system on a small number of home machines over a local network? Is there any software that makes this possible?

Comment: Yes - but it depends on what sort of computing you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Hapood and MPI both work on Linux. Most of the software involved in cluster computing these days is open-source.

Comment: Is there anything that works on windows based machines?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you want to learn or model real-world distributed computing you should run it on Linux. That's what everybody else does.

Comment: Just to note that Linux can be run in VMs (VMWare/VirtualBox) on each Windows machine, which should be okay for experimenting or proof of concept. Beyond that, you might want to also look into GPU computing - CUDA & such.

Comment: You can also run the freely licensed ESXi from VMware. With that you could potentially run many Linux and WIndows VMs, depending on your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for all the great responses. Are either of these options easy to implement or do they require professional skills?

Comment: If you can follow directions and know something about Unix/Linux you should be able to do it.